# Parse iOS - How to capture the findObjects() error being thrown?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am coding in Swift and attempting to use the findObjects() function for the Parse iOS SDK. However, I can't seem to figure out what type of error is being thrown by Parse if this function call fails. I'm a novice in Swift so that may be my issue. I attempt to call the function in a do->catch block and use the try keyword on the function call however I'm not sure what to catch. I can catch the error using the _ but I would like to grab the description from the error. Thanks!

P.S.  I don't want to use the findObjectsInBackground() method.

```
do {
    let object = try query.getFirstObject()
    // do something with the object
} catch _ {
    // this is where I would like to print out the error description
}
```

Comment: can you post your code? And why don't you want to use the findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock method?

Comment: @joey I added the code that I am trying to modify. I would like to change the _ to capture the error in a variable, but I am unsure how to go about doing that. I don't want to use the findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock method because it messes with the flow of my program so I am implementing concurrency another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Obj-C, which I assume will be similar, I print out the error.userInfo[@"error"] parameter of the NSError that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is print(error). An example here:

```
func getReferenceNumberAsStringSync() -> String? {
let query = PFQuery(className: "PropertyCount")
do {
  let object = try query.getFirstObject()
  if let referenceNumber = object["count"] as? Int {
    return String(referenceNumber)
  }
} catch  {
  print(error)
}
return nil
```

}